# I want to add value in list

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, lightning, controller

here is a error

```
for(Opportunity opp : Trigger.new){
    if(opp.AccountId != null){   //Variable does not exist: AccountId

        opptyIdToAccountId.add(opp.AccountId );      //Variable does not exist: AccountId
        oppOwnerId.add(opp.OwnerId);                //Variable does not exist: ownerId
        System.debug('#####opptyIdToAccountId'+opptyIdToAccountId);
        System.debug('#####oppOwnerId'+oppOwnerId);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this error occurs when your organization has a class named as `Opportunity`. Verify in your list of classes if it has any class named as `Opportunity`. If yes, then  either rename it to something else or delete it completely if not required.

This compile time error occurs because compiler always searches in custom classes first wherein if it finds your custom made `Opportunity` class, then searches for `AccountId` property in which if doesn't exist gives an compilation error.

Hence, you will have to rename or delete that custom `Opportunity` class so that the compiler understands that it should refer the standard `Opportunity` object

Compile all your classes post renaming and then try saving your changes.

You can compile all classes by navigating from Setup > Develop > Apex Classes > Click on Compile all classes

**Note :** You should never create classes with the names which are already being used by the platform.